# Algebraic loop error - help fixing spurious dependency

Tags: drake

**tldr: why is my plant being flagged as direct-feedthrough and how do I override this labeling?**

I've created a plant in Drake that takes a voltage input `phi` and uses that plus the system state `Lam` to calculate its derivatives `Lam_d`. I then plugged in the system to `FittedValueIteration` to generate my policy for controlling it. The value iteration successfully generated a policy (and upon inspection, it looks very reasonable), but when I attempt to hook it up to my system using a diagram builder, I receive the following message, indicating that I have direct-feedthrough:

```
RuntimeError: Reported algebraic loop detected in DiagramBuilder:
  InputPort[0] (phi) of System ::drake/pydrake/(anonymous)/Impl@000000000648eec0 (Impl<double>::PyLeafSystemBase<drake::pydrake::(anonymous)::Impl<double>::LeafSystemPublic>) is direct-feedthrough to
  OutputPort[0] (Lam) of System ::drake/pydrake/(anonymous)/Impl@000000000648eec0 (Impl<double>::PyLeafSystemBase<drake::pydrake::(anonymous)::Impl<double>::LeafSystemPublic>) is connected to
  InputPort[0] (u0) of System ::drake/systems/BarycentricMeshSystem@0000000005c6d300 (BarycentricMeshSystem<double>) is direct-feedthrough to
  OutputPort[0] (y0) of System ::drake/systems/BarycentricMeshSystem@0000000005c6d300 (BarycentricMeshSystem<double>) is connected to
  InputPort[0] (phi) of System ::drake/pydrake/(anonymous)/Impl@000000000648eec0 (Impl<double>::PyLeafSystemBase<drake::pydrake::(anonymous)::Impl<double>::LeafSystemPublic>)
```

I believe that there is indeed direct-feedthrough on the vi_policy (the barycentric mesh referenced in the error message), since it just takes in a state and spits out an output based on that. My plant, however, uses the controller's input to generate an acceleration, so I am confused as to why it's being flagged. My plant is shown below, for reference:

```
class DEAContinuousSys(LeafSystem):
  def __init__(self):
    LeafSystem.__init__(self)

    self.DeclareContinuousState(2) # two state variables: lam, lam_d
    self.DeclareVectorOutputPort('Lam', BasicVector(2), self.CopyStateOut) # two outputs: lam_d, lam_dd
    self.input_port = self.DeclareVectorInputPort('phi', BasicVector(1)) 

  def DoCalcTimeDerivatives(self, context, derivatives): 
    Lam = context.get_continuous_state_vector().get_value() # get state, cast as regular array
    phi = self.input_port.Eval(context)
    Lam_d = DEA.dynamics(Lam, None, phi) # derive acceleration (no timestep required)
    derivatives.get_mutable_vector().SetAtIndex(0, Lam_d[0]) # set velocity
    derivatives.get_mutable_vector().SetAtIndex(1, Lam_d[1]) # set acceleration

  def CopyStateOut(self, context, output):
    Lam = context.get_continuous_state_vector().CopyToVector()
    output.SetFromVector(Lam)
```

I figured that this direct-feedthrough notification was erroneous, but I was having trouble parsing the documentation to fix this issue. So I'm still trying to figure out:

1. **Why was this labeled as direct-feedthrough?**
2. **How do I add a ticket to indicate it is not direct-feedthrough? Is there a good example somewhere that I can reference?**

edit: re-reading the documentation, I see that the answer to 1. is that by default all LeafSystems will be set as direct-feedthrough to avoid accidental loops. Had my plant been a simple combination of symbolic expressions, it could have been properly interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, declarations of `OutputPort`s are dependent on *all* sources -- that includes input ports. It seems your output port is dependent only on your continuous state. You can modify your declaration to explicitly spell that out. That should make your algebraic loop go away.

Try:

```py
self.DeclareVectorOutputPort('Lam', BasicVector(2), self.CopyStateOut, 
                             prerequisites_of_calc=set([self.xc_ticket()]))
```

(I'm not 100% on the pydrake spelling, but I'd still lay money on this.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm a little confused, though, what you mean by it not being dependent on the input; within `DoCalcTimeDerivatives`, you can see that it depends on the input value `phi`. Are you saying that the only dependency that matters is the state dependency in the output port callback `CopyStateOut`?

Comment: That's the distinction between your *declared* output port and your time derivatives. Of course, your time derivatives depend on your inputs. But your declared output port simply copies Lam to an output port. *That* act is *not* dependent on your input ports.

Comment: For those reading after this, this was indeed the correct syntax. And thank you for the clarification! This is very useful.